# How to replace root ebs volume with another root ebs volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I accidentally formatted my system and the access keys to the ec2 volume were also deleted. So I stopped the instance and detached the ebs volume. 
However I am not able to attach it to another ec2 instance as root(/dev/sda1). Can anyone please guide me through it? All my data and server files are there in the volume.
I mounted the first ebs volume and on the 2nd instance and browsed the files in there. They are all intact. If it cannot be mounted on as root volume, I need a way to get all the mysql data from the volume as there are a number of wordpress websites hosted on it. I can access the wordpress files but I dont know how to get the database from the instance. 
Any of the solutions will save my life...
Thank you very much

Comment: Try to mount it under `/dev/sda` and not `/dev/sda1`

Comment: shall I stop the instance, detach the ebs volume and then attach the previous one as /dev/sda ?

Comment: You need to stop the instance you want to attach your root ebs. Detach its current root ebs, attach your new ebs under `/dev/sda` and start the instance.

Comment: Error attaching volume: Value (/dev/sda) for parameter device is invalid. /dev/sda is not a valid EBS device name I got this message when trying to do so..Please advise further

Comment: OK. Try to mount it as `/dev/xvda` and see how it goes. Second, when you tried to mount as `/dev/sda` what error did you get?

Comment: I attached the volume as /dev/xvda and tried to start the instance and got this error: Invalid value 'i-9d2ab41d' for instanceId. Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/sda1)

Comment: the attached instance is being attached as a block device...not as a root device..is there any way to control that?

Comment: That's because it needs to be mounted under `/dev/sda1`. What was the error you get when you tried that?

Comment: No problem. I summed it up and posted it as an answer for future reference.

Comment: Mounting under /dev/sda1 worked for me, unlike /dev/sda or /dev/xvda

Answer (score 24):

What you need to do:

1. Stop the instance
2. Detach the current root EBS
3. Attach you new EBS under `/dev/sda1` (for Linux) and `/dev/xvda` (for Windows)
4. Start your instance

Technically that's it. In case of problems, you can always attach the EBS as non-rooted EBS (such as `/dev/sdb`) and browse the files and fix the error if possible.

Comment: For my linux server I could not get it to work as /dev/sda1, but when I used /dev/xvda it worked

Comment: Was this with all filesystems in one partition?  What happens if you have repartitioned the disk and /boot and /root are under different partitions.  Does /boot or /root need to be 1?

Answer (score 6):

Short follow-up to [@Avihoo Mamka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455626/avihoo-mamka) answer.

If you have more than one disk attached to your instance and just want to change the root disk, you first have to detach all other disks and only after that you can add your new root disk as */dev/sda1* (for linux)

Answer (score -1):

attach to the new instance see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html

mount it in linux see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html but skip to step 5, do not do any formatting

Comment: I suspect you didn't read the question carefully. How are you going to "mount it in Linux" if you're replacing the boot volume?

Comment: @Corrodias I could have perhaps put more detail in my answer but I think this is covered in the other places mentioned!  Attachment to a new instance can be under a different device ( ie /dev/sdg ) so it doesn't "collide" with the boot volume ( often /dev/sda ).  The mounting under linux can be under a different point apart from root ( / ) for example /mnt.  If the partition is attached to the new instance as /dev/sdg and then mounted on linux with ``mount /dev/sdg /mnt`` then the data the OP is interested in which was under /home/centos is now mounted at /mnt/home/centos on the new instance