# How can I recover a AWS Centos AMI instance without using centos user to login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, authentication, centos

Embarrassingly, I inadvertently changed the owner of my /home/centos directory to another user that doesn't have login rights. Now when I try to login using the centos user, I receive "Permission Denied" message. But if I try to login as root, I receive "Please login as the user "centos" rather than "root". Is there any way out of this? Or is the server forever inaccessible?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Longer answer: if you need to recover something from the server, you can mount the root drive on another instance. This has been answered multiple times on this site (for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257790/how-to-replace-root-ebs-volume-with-another-root-ebs-volume)).

Comment: Thank you for responding. In my thinking about that solution, I can imagine the following problem. All the authentication settings, and the corruption of the owner/group of the centos user's home directory, are actually stored on the ebs volume. How would mounting it on another instance change any of that?

Comment: This slightly different solution may work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027806/how-to-login-to-remote-host-when-home-directory-is-777ed?rq=1

Comment: kdgregory - You must have meant to attach the old root drive to the new instance as a *data* volume. This will surely work.